# Random Polynomial TM

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I need to show that there exists random polynomial TM `M`, that uses `O(log(n))` space s.t.

> for input G,s,t where G is directed graph and s,t are two vertices in
>   G:   If there is a path from s to t then `Pr[M(G,s,t) = 1] ≥ 1/nⁿ`
>   Else `Pr[M(G,s,t)=1] = 0`

I tried to choose each time a random neighbor, but I can't figure why the probability is `1/nⁿ`,
and I'm not sure about the number of iterations.

And another question:
I need to use the above result and the fact that I have "random counter" that uses `O(log k)` space, and can count up to `2k`, to show that:

> L is in LN iff there exists random polynomial TM M that uses `O(log n)`
>   space and for every input x, M will spot and:   If x is in L then
>   `Pr[M(x) = 1] ≥ 1/2`   Else `Pr[M(x) = 1] = 0`

Comment: Hi Alex! This is probably better on our Math sites. Also, we don't typically do homework. Math has [specific rules](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1804/161146) about homework questions. ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is suitable for `(cs.stackexchange.com` OR `math.stackexchange.com)` AND it's way too broad!

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer the first question as this should be one question per post.

**Algorithm:**

1. start with vertice `s`
2. set a counter to zero.
3. choose a random neighbor `v`. (and increment the counter)
4. check if `v` equals `t`.
5. If not choose another random neighbor of `v`. (increment the counter)
6. repeat 3. and 4. until you found `t` or the counter reaches `n`. (or maybe `c⋅n` where `c` is a constant number)

To do this, you onlyhave to save 3 vertices (`s`,`v`,`t`) and the counter. If the counter is stored as binaray number it needs `log₂(n)` Bits. So this runs in `O(log(n))` space.

If there is no path from `s` to `t` you will never get a neighbors neighbor of `s` that is `t`, so `Pr[M(G,s,t)=1] = 0` holds.
If there exists a path, the propability of finding it would be the product of the propabilitys of choosing the right neighbors. So the worst case is that `g` is a complete graph, so evert vertice has `n-1` neighbors. The path cannot be longer than `n` vertices. So let `[s,v₁,v₂,...,vm,t]` a path from `s` to `t`, with `m < n`. The we get

```
Pr[M(G,s,t) = 1] ≥ Πk=1,...,m 1/|neighbors(vk)|
                 ≥ Πk=1,...,m 1/(n-1)
                 ≥ Πk=1,...,m 1/n
                 ≥ Πk=1,...,n 1/n
                 = 1/nⁿ
```